# Python - print only the highest number of collatz

Tags: python

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        return number // 2
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        result = 3 * number + 1
        print(result)
        return result

#4. zolang n ongelijk is aan 0, niet stoppen.
n = input("invoer: ")
while n != 1:
    n = collatz(int(n))
```

I've got this code, but I only want to print the highest number in place of the whole queue of collatz sequence.
How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can be refactored to print the maximum number from the Collatz Sequence as follows:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number // 2
    else:
        return (3 * number) + 1

# Refactored this part because Collatz Conjecture is defined for positive
# numbers only
try:
    n = int(input('invoer: '))
    if n <= 0:
        raise ValueError
except ValueError:
    print('Enter a valid positive integer')

# Set a variable to store maximum value
max_num = 0 

while n != 1:
    # If the current number is bigger than existing maximum number, update it
    max_num = max(n, max_num)
    n = collatz(int(n))

print('Maximum number is {}'.format(max_num))
```

Note that I have updated some of your original code so that only positive integer is a valid input. This is because [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) states that the sequence starts with a positive integer.

Also, in the `if-else` construct, you do not need to write the condition for odd numbers explicitly because if the integer is not even then it must be odd.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a max variable which you update with `n`, if `n` is larger than that variable's value:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number // 2
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        return 3 * number + 1

n = input('invoer: ')
m = 0
while n != 1:
    if n > m: m = n
    n = collatz(int(n))

print('the max was:', m)
```

With the input `5` gives `16`, since `16` is the max of `[5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]`.